# Calculating the number of years in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've written a messy function which calculates the number of years in a dataframe based on it's length (assuming the dataframe has values for each day of the year).

It works fine, but it's a lot of code that could be made much smarter (but I'm not sure how...)

Here is the function, it only goes to 10 years, I want it to work for a dataset of any size. I could extend it further by copying and pasting and adding the totals up further, but there must be a smarter way to write this code.

```
def numyears(x):
    if len(x.index) <= 366:
        return 1
    elif len(x.index) <= 732:
        return 2
    elif len(x.index) <= 1098:
        return 3
    elif len(x.index) <= 1464:
        return 4
    elif len(x.index) <= 1830:
        return 5
    elif len(x.index) <= 2196:
        return 6
    elif len(x.index) <= 2562:
        return 7
    elif len(x.index) <= 2928:
        return 8
    elif len(x.index) <= 3294:
        return 9
    elif len(x.index) <= 3660:
        return 10
    else: 
        return 'ERROR'
```

Comment: Do you have timestamps or any datetime values associated with your index or row values?

Comment: Yes the row values have a datetime object associated with them

Comment: So this is a column or is it the index?

Comment: Sorry - It's a column

Comment: See my updated answer, it should work

Comment: @EdChum thanks for the update - this works, but I only want to calculate full years. If there's only half a year in the dataset, this method counts it as a full year.

Comment: Well your question lacked sufficient detail, one method would be to do `df.groupby([df['some_col'].dt.year, df['some_col'].dt.day]).count() >= 365` and get the `len` of this

Comment: @edchum thanks - I think the most straightforward process is to remove the incomplete years from the analysis - then use your `df['date_col'].dt.year.nunique()` suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems more reasonable to just access the `year` attribute and then just get the `len` of the unique values:

```
In [2]:
s = pd.date_range(dt.datetime(1900,1,1), end=dt.datetime(2000,1,1), freq='6M')
s

Out[2]:
DatetimeIndex(['1900-01-31', '1900-07-31', '1901-01-31', '1901-07-31',
               '1902-01-31', '1902-07-31', '1903-01-31', '1903-07-31',
               '1904-01-31', '1904-07-31',
               ...
               '1995-01-31', '1995-07-31', '1996-01-31', '1996-07-31',
               '1997-01-31', '1997-07-31', '1998-01-31', '1998-07-31',
               '1999-01-31', '1999-07-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=200, freq='6M')

In [8]:
len(np.unique(s.year))

Out[8]:
100
```

this way it handles infrequent periods, missing days, entries that overlap year boundaries etc.

You can also convert the index to a `Series` and call `nunique`:

```
In [11]:
s.to_series().dt.year.nunique()

Out[11]:
100
```

Seeing as you already have datetime as a column then just this will work:

```
df['date_col'].dt.year.nunique()
```

If necessary you can convert to datetime using:

```
df['date_col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'])
```

**UPDATE**

so it seems your requirement is to count complete years, if you set the index to the year and day component then you can count at the year level and then filter the rows that are not >= 365 to give you the number of complete years:

```
In [34]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range(dt.datetime(1900,6,1), end=dt.datetime(1910,6,1))})
count = df.set_index([df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.day]).count(level=0)
count

Out[34]:
      date
date      
1900   214
1901   365
1902   365
1903   365
1904   366
1905   365
1906   365
1907   365
1908   366
1909   365
1910   152

In [39]:
len(count[count >= 365].dropna())

Out[39]:
9
```

Comment: This is definitely the right way to do it if the DataFrame has dates, but if it's just sequential, non-timestamped entries for some reason, it obviously won't work.

Comment: @Paul please explain how this won't work for timestamps

Comment: I think he was saying it won't work if they aren't timestamps

Comment: I guess that's true so I've asked the OP to indicate if there are any timestamp/datetime values in the rows

Comment: Yeah, I don't know why you wouldn't have timestamped data, but I'm also not sure why the OP was taking a row-counting approach in the first place rather than using the actual date data...

Answer (score 4):

Just divide the length of the index by 365

```
def numyears(x):
     return len(x.index) / 365 # use // for python 3
```

As written this will do integer division and match the output you have here.  This will scale a dataframe of any size

**EDIT** The above solution takes a floor approach, after re-reading the post, the OP used a ceiling approach. For that

```
return len(x.index) / 365 + 1
```

Comment: There's 365 days in a year, with the exception of leap years

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Change `/` to `//` for Python 3.

Comment: Integer division in python takes the floor, but example function is taking the ceiling, so you need to add 1.

Comment: Edited solution to show both floor and ceiling approach and python 3 integer division

Comment: Add one to the result, not number of days.  `1 + len(x.index)/365`.

Comment: @root, was careless.  Updated yet again

Comment: I don't think there's any reason to use `/` in Python 2 if you mean `//`. Also, I think `len(x.index) // 365.25` will give more accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a set out of all the years, and then return its length.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(365*10, 3), 
                  columns=list('ABC'), 
                  index=pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=365*10))

# Number of unique years
>>> len(set(ts.year for ts in df.index))
10
```

If your index is of type datetime or string, you first need to convert it to a Timestamp:

```
>>> len(set(ts.year for ts in pd.to_datetime(df.index)))
10
```